# code to pull data from another sheet if a key word is typed into Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a wordbook with multiple sheets. I have a sheet called “Info” that contains hundreds of rows of employees. Each employee is assigned an employee number in column B; the remainder of the row (24 columns) contains the rest of the employee’s personal information).
 I have another sheet called “data” that only requires a group of 20 to 40 people that can vary from day to day
I want to be able to enter an employee number (ex: SN124523) into an empty cell in column B on Sheet called “Data”. I would then like the remainder of the row to self-populate with the employee information from the “Info” sheet. 
  I need to do this with up to 40 employees, so regardless of which cell I select in column B on the “Data” sheet I would like it to search the “info “sheet on import the information.
I have made this work with a VLOOKUP formula, but because multiple people sometimes use this book and I sometime have to delete and replace the "info" Sheet That I always end up with a #REF error in the formulas.

I tried something like this for just a few lines of data as a trial but I can’t get anything to work.

```
Sub Add_member()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim iRow, row_count As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("Info")
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Data")

row_count = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For iRow = 2 To row_count

If ws1.Cells(iRow, 2) = ws.Cells(iRow, 2) Then
ws1.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value
ws1.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value
‘ I would need this to fill 24 columns in total.
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any help Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub Add_member()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim f As Range, c As Range, rng As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Info")
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Data")

    Set rng = ws1.Range("B2", ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            Set f = ws.Columns(2).Find(what:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                       lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                c.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 24).Value = _
                                   f.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 24).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, Both methods worked! You saved me so much grief.

Comment: @Stunasmearse, consider up voting those answers that you found helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @TimWilliams, shouldn't `"A2"` be `"B2"`?

Comment: Yes - fixed above.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `Event_Handler` in this situation. Therefore when you enter the number the data is automatically updated for you.

Assuming `B1` is the cell you will be entering the number to be looked up.

Post the below code into the `WorkSheet module`, enter a number and the data should appear for that number in row 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   Dim fCell As Range
   Dim rng As Range

     Application.EnableEvents = 0
      Set ws = Worksheets("Info")
      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
            Set fCell = ws.Range("B2:B1000").Find(What:=Target, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
          Target.Resize(, 24).Value = fCell.Resize(, 24).Value
        Else
          MsgBox "No number exists."
          Range("B1:Y1").ClearContents
        End If
      End If
     Application.EnableEvents = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI your code will error if the user updates >1 cell in a single operation.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I don't follow?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I see what you are talking about now. It can't error, I have only specified a single cell as the target.  A simple line of code like this would clear multiple cell updates `If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then GoTo ExitSub` and put `ExitSub` above  `Application.EnableEvents = 1`. If he wants bulk updates, then that is simple as well, surely you should know that?

Comment: It can error - checking with Intersect only ensures at least one cell in Target is B1, and a Target range of B1:B5 would pass that test, but then you can't use What:=Target in the next line...

Comment: @TimWilliams, that will not throw an error b/c the other cells in the `Target` range do not `Intersect` with the single celll. The `If Not` will always send it to the `Else`, or `End` in this case, of the if statement, and will never reach this `What:=Target `.

Comment: It *will* throw an error, because you can't use a multi-cell range as the first argument to `Find()`: if you still think I'm wrong, please try it out before telling me so.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I have never stated that the `find()` will not throw an error, I am saying it will never reach the the `find()`, the `If` statement will ensure that. I have tried, it won't go past the the if statement.

Comment: You tried changing (eg) B1:B5 and it didn't error? When I tried that with your code I got a "Type Mismatch" error with Find().  It's not a big deal - I'm happy to leave it alone.

Comment: @TimWilliams, no error. Running this `?Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B2"))` in the intermediate window gives an `Run time error 91`, which is what you would expect when the range has not being set, normally that would give you the value of the `Target cell`.  So I can only assume that the `Intersect` is doing its job in this case. I am using Excel 2016 BTW.  No, I am happy to meat this out, b/c ,if this is unusual behavior I certainly want to know why and can vaguely recall encountering what you are saying in past applications I have built.

Comment: Put some values in C1:C5 then copy-paste those values at B1:B5. If you change multiple cells in one shot (eg by copy-paste or selecting multiple cells and using Ctrl+Enter to enter a value), then `Target` is a single range containing all of the changed cells.  If only *one* of those cells happens to be B1, then the whole of the `Target` range passes the `Intersect()` test, and so proceeds into the call to `Find()` (where it causes the error)

Comment: If you want to avoid this then it's best to set a Range variable to the return value from `Intersect()`, which will contain only the cells common to both of the range arguments - in this case B1 - and pass *that* into Find() instead of the whole Target range.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I was able to reproduce that. I guess the 'you can'T predict what a user will do' comes into play. But anyway, this`If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then GoTo ExitSub` will fix that issue as I already posted. I did not know we had to do error handling as well for the OP. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

assuming

- employee number is a string (like "SN124523")
- there's always one employee number at least
- employee numbers are input in a contiguous range in sheet "data" column B (i.e. n blanks between them)

then you could use

```
Sub Add_member()
    Worksheets("Data").Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).offset(, 2).Resize(, 24).FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC2,Info!C2:C27,column()-1)"
End Sub
```

or, should you want to get rid of formulas:

```
Sub Add_member()
    With Worksheets("Data").Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).offset(, 2).Resize(, 24)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC2,Info!C2:C27,column()-1)"
        .value = .value
    End With
End Sub
```

of course all the above assumptions can be removed and the code changed accordingly.

but the one above just to show the shortest possible

Comment: @Stunasmearse, did you try this?

Comment: @Stunasmearse, It'd be fine of you to give feedbacks to people trying helping you